# "height=100%" doesn't work in IE9

Tags: css

I have HTML defined as this.

```
<div class="a">
     <div class="b" >
         something
     </div>
     <div class="c" >
         <div class="d">
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS style is defined as:

```
html,body
{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.a
{
    display:table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 99%;
    background: green;
    padding-top: 10px;
    float: left;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.b
{
    background: yellow;
    display:table-row;
    padding-bottom: 10pt;
    margin-left: 5pt;
    float: left;

}
.c
{
    background: pink;
    display:table-row;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.d
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

In Firefox, Safari, Chrome, the div with class "d" has the same height with its parent div element. But in IE9, the height of div with class "d" is equal to 0. Does anybody know the reason.

Here is the link of above test code
http://jsfiddle.net/ZDY4P/19/

Comment: Most things in IE9 don't conform to standards.  I think Microsoft does this on purpose to prevent the market being saturated by web developers.

Comment: IE probably doesn't handle the block element inside of a div defined as a table row the the same way other browsers who aren't as "strict" and non conforming as Microsoft is.

Comment: In IE, a block does not work with table elements by setting percentage

Comment: I'm probably going to get flogged for this, but: does it work if you use an actual table instead of divs?

Comment: [FLOG! FLOG! FLOG!](http://jspivey.wikispaces.com/file/view/flogging.gif/31496205/flogging.gif)

Comment: What about changing .d to inline-block instead of block?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the float property in **.d**. And use a **table-cell** for **.d** within the display:table-row that **.c** stands for. Works in IE9:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZDY4P/45/

```
.d
{
    background: orange; /* added a marker color */
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%; /* or 50% or auto for multiple columns... */
    height: 100%;
}
```

If you are in need to have multiple columns of 100% height inside **.c**, add multiple D's as shown in the jsfiddle.

To IE9's honour: I don't have a list, which kind of display nestings are allowed, but nesting `display:block; float: left` inside a `display:table-row` is maybe somewhat invalid, speaking old-HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <div> <!-- expected: a <td> -->
       ..
```